# What's the best way to handle questions that generate multiple answers, each of which has only part of the answer?

Tags: discussion

Several times I've received multiple answer to a question I asked, with each question having good information but only a portion of the answer. For example, in this recent question:

[Which tournament format best emphasizes winning (as opposed to avoiding last place)?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/7159/which-tournament-format-best-emphasizes-winning-as-opposed-to-avoiding-last-pla)

After reading the three answers and various questions/comments to the answers, I now have a good answer. But it wasn't any one answer or comment that provided the answer. It was all of them collectively.

Here are other examples I've run across (the last Q is not mine):

[What is optimal end play in Settlers?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/6984/what-is-optimal-end-play-in-settlers)

[What is a good resource to discover new games?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/6185/what-is-a-good-resource-to-discover-new-games/6191#6191)

So how to handle this? Do I need to improve the question? Is it best to work with the better of the 3 answers and see if I can get that person to incorporate information from the other 2 answers and various comments? Or is it better practice to try to write a completely new answer that tries to pull together all the other answers and comments into a more complete and coherent whole?

NOTE: I suggested in response to the blog idea that content with multiple answers could be reworked into a blog post. The above 3 Q&As cited are examples where rewriting into a blog post would likely be better than the original Q&A - especially if it were done by someone with specific expertise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have questions that lean towards the subjective side, It's more likely that one answer won't cover the whole solution.  I think that's ok.  You can vote up as many of the answers as you want. So if you end up with several answers with high scores, a reader should be able to tell that there's not a single consensus on the subject.

Alternativly answers can be made into [community wikis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741).  This is a good built in feature to make more inclusive answers when we need to.

Comment: The only thing I would add to this is that you can (and probably should) select as "accepted" the answer that is most useful to you at some point.  Maybe a week or so after the question is asked.  If an answer improves, you can always switch the accepted mark.  The answer shouldn't have to be perfect to get your approval IMHO.